# How To Bind select event for bs-datepicker directive for angular bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using [Angular-ui](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/##datepickers) and I'm unable to bind the select event when the date is selected.

Can anyone help me, I tried to edit the bs-datepicker directive to add a scope and pass function from controller but could not do it.

Please help me.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Can you just $watch the date?

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/RrOsCSPk2aAFFd3EfUH4?p=preview)

```
  $scope.$watch('selectedDate', function(newV, oldV){
     if(newV){
       alert(newV);
     }
  });
```

Comment: I also thought about it, But in my case its difficult as i have a complex ng-repeat which renders the date picker dynamic models actually.

Comment: I got the required thing I made a directive and then passed it a controller function to listen the watch event from directive which would trigger the controller function.